# Android phone - logging into Pokemon Go account without adding the Google account to my phone

Tags: pokemon-go

I had a fairly good Pokemon Go account that I put a lot of time into. It was linked through one of my Google accounts. However I was having a lot of issues with other aspects of that Google account and didn't want it synced to my phone anymore. So I got rid of it and started a fresh Google account. Now though, when I try to log in to Pokemon Go, it wants me to add the Google account, and that's the only option for logging in. I really don't want it all re-synced to my phone, so how can I just log in by typing the email and password, and not adding the account back on to my phone? Or, can I link the email to a Trainer account, and then log in with a trainer id? There has to be a way around having that account back on my phone. I don't want to start a new game....

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: Since you resolved the issue, you can write in your own answer to help others who encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

They added the option to log in with Google account just to make the login easier. If you want to make a new account, you should make a Pokémon Trainer Club account. If you want to log in with another Google account, you need to log out and then log in with the second account. I don't believe that there's another method.

Comment: To clarify, it's not possible to log into Pokemon Go with a Google account that is not added to the phone.